# Bash scripting variable not populating

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I made a simple script to guess the word for wordle using letter elimination. This script works perfects on my Zorin OS laptop but when I try it on an Ubuntu 20.04 server it fails.  As near as I can tell the its failing because a variable isn't getting populated in Ubuntu when it does in Zorin.

```
echo "Enter ther letters to eliminate."
read Eletters
echo $Eletters >> /tmp/letters.txt
echo "Eliminated Letters"
tr -d '\n' < /tmp/letters.txt | tee /tmp/letters.txt
EL=$(cat /tmp/letters.txt)
grep -Evi "([$EL])" /tmp/wordleguesses.txt > /tmp/wordleguesses2.txt
```

If I do an echo $EL I get nothing in Ubuntu but in Zorin I get the letters stored in /tmp/letters.txt.

I'm not sure why Ubuntu doesn't accept this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for the suggestion but that did not provide any explanation for why EL is not populating in Ubuntu.  Again it works fine in Zorin but not Ubuntu.

Comment: You've tagged the question `bash` but I don't see an actual shebang to indicate the shell; regardless, I don't think you should rely on `tee` not truncating `/tmp/letters.txt` on the RHS of the pipe before the shell on the LHS redirects it to `tr` - there doesn't seem to be any good reason to use files here at all really - why not just `EL=$(tr -d '\n' < /tmp/letters.txt)` or `EL=$(tr -d '\n' <<< "$Eletters")`, or even `EL=${Eletters//$'\n'/}`?

Comment: Possibly because you have eliminated ALL the NewLine (Use `"\n"`) characters and `cat` wants 1? `(tr -d "\n" </tmp/letters.txt ;echo) | ...` will supply a NL at the end.

Comment: @steeldriver this is only a portion of the script so the shebang is not visible. I didn't want to post the entire script as the rest of it works fine, but thank you. I'll give your recommendations a try.

Comment: @steeldriver I tested your solutions and while they work for giving EL a value they cause a separate problem. The file were so that each time the script runs more letters get eliminated. ie. if the letters abc were eliminated the first time then I want them to stay elimined and add whatever letters are input for Eletters (say hij).  So then grep now cuts out words with abchij in them.

Comment: @waltinator, ~~no dice unfortunately. Still the same thing.~~

Edit: Actually, that seems to have fixed it. Adding in an echo $EL still shows nothing but the letters are being eliminated properly now.

Comment: @Dan.T in that case I suggest you [edit] your question to make clear its purpose, preferably with a reproducible example of input + desired output

Comment: ... you may also want to take a look at using `sponge` in place of `tee` - see for example [Can I read and write to the same file in Linux without overwriting it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36268/65304)